# Memory leak from Objective-C code in iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c

My code is eating memory. I added this function and it seems to the cause of all the problems as when I dont call it then I don't run out.

It's a function in Objective-C to crop an image. How do I release the memory that was used in the auction so that at the end of the function everything is cleaned up before exiting.

```
-(void) crop: (CVImageBufferRef)sampleBuffer
{
    int cropX0, cropY0, cropHeight, cropWidth, outWidth, outHeight;

    cropHeight = 720;
    cropWidth = 1280;
    cropX0 = 0;
    cropY0 = 0;

    outWidth = 1280;
    outHeight = 720;

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(sampleBuffer,0);
    void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(sampleBuffer);
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(sampleBuffer);

    vImage_Buffer inBuff;
    inBuff.height = cropHeight;
    inBuff.width = cropWidth;
    inBuff.rowBytes = bytesPerRow;

    int startpos = cropY0*bytesPerRow+4*cropX0;
    inBuff.data = baseAddress+startpos;

    unsigned char *outImg= (unsigned char*)malloc(4*outWidth*outHeight);
    vImage_Buffer outBuff = {outImg, outHeight, outWidth, 4*outWidth};

    vImage_Error err = vImageScale_ARGB8888(&inBuff, &outBuff, NULL, 0);
    if (err != kvImageNoError)
    {
        NSLog(@" error %ld", err);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Success");
    }


    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = NULL;
    OSStatus result = CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                   inBuff.width,
                                                   inBuff.height,
                                                   kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA,
                                                   outImg,
                                                   bytesPerRow,
                                                   NULL,
                                                   NULL,
                                                   NULL,
                                                   &pixelBuffer);


    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(sampleBuffer,0);

}
```

Comment: `unsigned char *outImg= (unsigned char*)malloc(4*outWidth*outHeight);`  where's your matching free?

Comment: Aside - if this is in C; why have you tagged it c++ and objective-c?  You've tagged it with 2 languages that it's not, and missed the one it is!

Comment: c, c++ and objective-c are different languages. Your tags, your question body and your sample code don't agree on which language you are asking about.

Comment: No, its not C, it is Objective-C, the tag is right, the description is wrong.

Comment: Objective-C is a superset of C. So stating that your "C is extremely basic" means that your Objective-C is also basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

free(outImg); 
at the end missing since you are not freeing the memory allocated.
It is a good practice in embedded programming and also here since you have const size pixel dimensions to use a const matrix that you can declare at the top of the function and initialized to zero.

Comment: Might explain why :)  malloc needs to be matched with free.